# jQuery WebStorage not storing variable on-click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store the data attribute of an `<a>` tag and keep it stored using localstorage, I currently have this block of code:

```
jQuery('.addtocart').on('click', function(){

  //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
  var vehicleRegistration = jQuery(this).data('value');
  //save it to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


  //read from localStorage
  if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
    //add the value to the form input
    jQuery('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
  }

});
```

I am also running prototype.js FYI.

I then have this `<a>` tag on my page that links to another page that contains a form:

```
<a href="/book-testdrive" class="addtocart" data-value="NH06LKO" title="Book Test Drive">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i>
    <span>&nbsp;Book Test Drive</span>
</a>
```

When I press the `<a>` tag it should store the data value within it however whenever I `console.log` the `vehicleRegistration` variable it give me a `Uncaught ReferenceError: vehicleRegistration is not defined` and doesn't store the data-value attribute.

Any idea where I might be going wrong? You can view the live site toi better underatand here: http://drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.html

The `<a>` tag is on every listed vehicle.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Is vehicleRegistration is a string or an object?

Answer (score 0):

As .addtocart is a link so you must first stop its default behaviour. 
Pass event to click event and prevent. Its working for me.

```
    <script>
        jQuery('.addtocart').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  //get the value of the "data-value" attribute for that link
  var vehicleRegistration = jQuery(this).data('value');
  //save it to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('vehicleRegistration', vehicleRegistration);


  //read from localStorage
  if( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') ){
    //add the value to the form input
    jQuery('#field34').val( localStorage.getItem('vehicleRegistration') );
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I've just tried adding this and I am getting exactly the same issue. Any idea why?

Comment: have you added e.preventDefault() and passing e in function ?

Comment: I just added the block of code you have gave me above. I am way out of my depth with this sort of JS so should that just work? Here is the page with that added: http://drivencarsales.co.uk/used-cars.html